# Does the new Air (2012) support Daisy Chaining to two Thunderbolt Displays?

Tags: macbook-pro, thunderbolt-display

Does the new MacBook Air (mid-2012) support Daisy Chaining to two Thunderbolt Displays?  I'm trying to decide between a fully-loaded MacBook Air and a Retina MacBook Pro, and this is a big breaking point for me.

Comment: @CajunLuke thnx luke

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes you can.

Source: http://support.apple.com/kb/HT5219?viewlocale=en_US#11